# What class of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, discrete-mathematics

PLEASE HELP ME Describe the class of sequences $$(x_n) _{n=1} ^∞ $$ that satisfy the condition $$ (∃\varepsilon>0)(∃n_{\varepsilon})(∃n>n_{\varepsilon}):|x_n−a|<\varepsilon $$ Give me an example . I think it is maybe a convergent sequence that has a border, but I can't write it down correctly (I am confused by these quantifiers, but such a condition is given in the exercise

Comment: As it is written now, any sequence of real numbers satisfies this condition. Maybe some of the $\exists$ are actually $\forall$?

Comment: Let $\varepsilon=2\left|x_2-a\right|,\, n_{\varepsilon}=1, \,n=2.$ If the first and third $\exists$ were changed to $\forall,$ you’d have the sequences converging to $a.$

Comment: No, all quantifiers are correct, it's just a condition of the tasks.
Therefore I am confused by these quantifiers, but such a condition is given in the exercise